# Toggle Button yellow light/dash

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

I made an App with several Toggle Buttons among other constrols. In certain circumstances some of those Toggle Buttons are set checked and unchecked not phisically by the user, but programmatically.

The tests in the Android Virtual Machine shows a normal behaviour of these controls, when I check and uncheck the Toggle Buttons both phisically and programmatically.

But my surprise comes when I run the App in a real Android machine: 
When unchecking any Toggle Button programmatically (no matter if I use the setChecked(false) or the toggle() functions), the Toggle Button indeed goes to the OFF state but with a yellow light/dash instead of an empty gray dash as it would be normal to infer... (Of course, when unchecking the button phisically, the problem doesn't exist)

No matter if I use:

```
toggleb.setChecked(false);
```

or...

```
toggleb.toggle();
```

Approximated Image:

[image: Approximated Image]

I suspect that it is related to the Android version of the real device that is more advanced than the Android Virual Machine...

So, I would like to know how to turn off any dash/light of the Toggle Button programmatically when setting it up to the OFF state.

I search all over the web for that circumstance, but, incredibly, I found no mention of it...

Thank you very much in advance...

---

I have to add an update:

The problem appears under specific and complex conditions and only in some Android devices, as if it were a kind of unwanted side effect. This is why this problem is so strange and does not appear in eclipse's Virtual machine (API 10: Android 2.3.3) and appears in my LG G3. I have to clarify it after several tests I made because I was not aware of it.

The App where I found the problem has a large and complex code where the ToggleButtons are not activated directly by the usual OnClick method, but by an OnTouch method whose Listener is linked to a ImageView (with a View it is the same) element that covers the whole Android device screen area.

So, this virtual element cover all buttons and controls of the App. Activating the buttons is made by registering the touch coordinantes by the OnTouch method and checking if that coordinates match the area of some of the ToggleButtons.

If the coordinates match the area of one given ToggleButton and is not checked (turned off), then that ToggleButton is checked (turned on).

On the contrary,  If the coordinates match the area of one given ToggleButton and is checked (turned on), then that ToggleButton is unchecked (turned off).

With some conditions, unchecking one ToggleButton, will uncheck others. This is the point where the problem appears: when unchecking the others, the yellow dash appears only in these others.

If I put some of these other ToggleButtons over the virtual screen (or transparent ImageView element), incredibly, the problem disappear for those ones, but the onTouch fucntion does not work for direct touch for those ones, so this could not be a solution for me.

I have to report all of this. 
Sorry, I still can't put code because it is very large and complex.
Thank you in advance.